# ImageView onClick opens Sliding Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

So I have an app that uses some buttons to go to different activities. Below them, I have imagebuttons that I want to use 2 of them to open 2 different sliding menus. I have already read, all about Sliding Menus from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer) but it only show a certain way of using a sliding menu.

So the code for the activity is that:

```
public class ChooseCategory extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_category);
}
```

and my xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#BE2625"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/fancy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/fancy"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/chipchop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chipchop"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/pizza"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pizza"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/asian"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/asian"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/indian"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/indian"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/kebab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kebab"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/other"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/other"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button4"
    />  
   </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#BE2620" >



                <!-- contentDescription tags added to remove related warnings -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                  />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_find_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                  />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                  />


    </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>


</RelativeLayouts>
```

Any help, on how to use that code or another code in order to click on ImageButton and open a Sliding menu?

Comment: You want to open sliding menu by clicking an image-view. Is this you want to ask?

Comment: How to open a Sliding Menu from an ImageButton. Because on the link above I cannot understand how to use it for an Imagebutton.

Comment: Check this, http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/11/simple-sliding-menu-example-in-android.html

Comment: It is the icon on Action bar. Its callled Navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for my project.

Call

```
getSlidingMenu().toggle(); //to open left side menu
```

and call

```
getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu(); //to open right side menu
```

Also if you want to open menus after clicking icons from SherlockActionBar

Modify `onOptionsItemSelected` method in BaseActivity as following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    case R.id.github:
        //Util.goToGitHub(this);
        showSecondaryMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

extend `BaseActivity` to your class

```
public class ChooseCategory extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_category);

        ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSlidingMenu().toggle(); // to open left side menu
            }
        }

        ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu(); // to open right side menu
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, but these method getSlidingMenu() what should I put inside it?

Comment: It doesn't recognize BaseActivity

Comment: And not only that getSlidingMenu it isn't recognizable. Should I have SherlockActionBar to do that?